# css error in w3schools validator for audio:not ( [ controls])

Tags: css, audio, controls

Can someone please tell me why is this shown as error in w3schools

```
audio:not ( [ controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the space between `:not` and `(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid unnecessary spaces, currently Firefox is not giving support to selectors like that (And Firefox is the one who follows the rules better

```
audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked! If so you can mark it as right answer for future views :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Turnip said, try this:

```
audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}
```